# Correct ajax post syntax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello I'm trying to post data to a database and it's working with get, but not with post.

Here's my javascript:

```
function updateShout(id)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", location.href);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send("edit="+document.getElementById("EDITM").value+"&id="+id);
    return false;
}
```

I'm making an ajax request to the current page with: index.php?edit=message&id=X

PHP is working fine, but I believe it's something with this line:

```
http.send("edit="+document.getElementById("EDITM").value+"&id="+id);
```

PHP (if needed):

```
if($_SESSION['signedin'])
{
    if(!is_blank($_REQUEST['edit'])) //if empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
    {
        $id = toNum( $_REQUEST['id'] ); //if(!is_numeric($val)) return -1; return (int)$val;
        $msg = htmlentities($_REQUEST['edit']); //secure dis
        $query = $db->query("UPDATE shouts SET shout='$msg' WHERE shoutid='$id'");
        $db->close();
        exit;
    }
}
```

please close.. found my issue. my  had name instead of id as "EDITM"

Comment: Remember to `window.encodeURIComponent` on your data

Comment: I thought that's what this method was for: http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: You say "_I'm making an ajax request to the current page with: index.php?edit=message&id=X_"... it sounds like you are sending GET headers then, so then it would not work with POST

Comment: @pattyd sorry I mispoke, If I change the PHP to get and enter that url it will update, but not when I post.

Comment: If the PHP is working fine then what is the issue?  You are not assigning a handler to the `onreadystatechange` event.

Comment: Oh i see! Sorry I just got a bit confused about that line. What you say makes sense though. +1 btw.

Comment: Just for the lulz .. I hope your not on a browser that doesn't support XMLHttpRequest Object ... Dam you ActiveXObject ;)

Comment: Are you trying to access values in the query string using `$_POST['edit']` by chance?

Comment: @pattyd - I agree with Paul S - You should encode your data using `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @woofmeow who uses ie? haha

Comment: Yes to `encodeURIComponent`. If your data has any & characters, you're toast.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and make sure all of your values are as you expect.

Comment: @marteljn okay I'll report back.

Comment: @marteljn yep.. var dump showed nothing was being posted as the message... turns out my <input> had name of "EDITM" and not id of "EDITM"

Comment: `$msg = htmlentities($_REQUEST['edit']); //secure dis`  Why are you mangling your data before putting it in your database?  Don't.  You may need the original form at some point, if you want to use it in a context other than HTML.  Also, use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks and related troubles.